# GeoServer mosaic - Innertiling slow

Tags: geoserver, style, tiles, mosaic

I have mosaic rasters/vectors from db - as a layergroup.
Individually layers do work quite well, and as a group decently at mid zoom/low high,
but when zoomed to close, rendeering gets really slow.
Seems that when Innertiling the rasters it starts to choke, I optimised stylings so that only the lowest amount of the layers need to be rendered per view level, this increased rendering speed on the mid/high, but low is still slow.
Rasters 1000x1000, avaraged to 2 4 8 16 32 64, tilesize 256.
Some of the vectors are on a different CRS.(Can be chanced if relates to this heavily, but need to adjust style levels also etc.)

Is there some clear known bottleneck(s) on the innertiling related to the way data has been prepared or I just missing something on styling/settings etc?